# How to get a Telerik Grid to display only records with todays date on?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid

I need a Telerik grid to only display records where the date recorded matches today's date.

**Edit** - Presently I have the db connected up to my project via an edmx but the only kind of filtering I've done before on the tables has been in viewmodels to work with drop downs, so I'm unsure what steps I need to take with a Telerik grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply filter the datasource before binding.

**EDIT:**

Supposedly you are using the MVC extensions from Telerik then you might do something like:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("Grid")
        .Filterable(filtering => filtering.Filters(filters => 
        {
            filters.Add(o => o.ContactName).StartsWith("Paul").And().EndsWith("Wilson");
        }))
%>
```

As seen on the Telerik demos: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/filtering

I've only used the Telerik library with WebForms and it's a bit different there.

Comment: Any example of what you mean? (I'm getting the data from a table in my db which is connected up via a edmx but that table can't be changed and needs to be able to store all previous records of w/e dates in case thats what you refering too.)

Comment: You don't need to mess with the table, just the query. Or are you saying you are binding directly to the table? In this case you might want to query the table and filter the date field so you obtain a dataset containing just what you need. Then bind this dataset to the grid.

Comment: Not sure if I'm fully understanding this so I'll explain more as my edit to my question as to how I presently have things.

Comment: Edit added to question with extra details

Comment: Can you show a little code where you bind the grid to your data?

Comment: Thats to add in a filter object/field to input something into and then filter a field by that isn't it? also turns out I did know how to get this to work I had just thought the correct way wouldn't work because it wouldn't accept more than 1 filter to it which wasn't true it's just the filter I had entered to have it get all the records for that day of a certain category was bugging out over the category part of the filter, basically I want on index page to choose in drop down a category then submit and go to list page which will show all records for that category and it's proving hard to do.

Comment: with ofc the filter of todays date on it just I didn't have space to add that into my last comment, I'd like to add it in here [List<'insert name'DTO> ret = new List<'insert name'DTO>();
            _bdb.'insert name'.Where(w => w.ID == Id && w.DATE == DateTime.Today).ToList().ForEach(x => ] problem is the field which I have to match up is a string and somehow with me seeting it up it has not only don't display any results but also seems to have lost all styling.

Comment: anyway since u made the best efford towards answering this question I'll mark it correct tomoz to give you time to read this comment, if there's anychance u can help me http://stackoverflow.com/q/5300656/536217 it would be a great help thx

Answer (score 1):

Just need to add a Where clause to your query whether your using Entity Framework or T-SQL and check your datetime column against the current date .NET DateTime.Now() or in T-SQL GetDate()

Examples

myDB.myTable.Where(m => m.CreateDate == DateTime.Now())

or

Select col1, col2, colDate From table1 Where colDate = GetDate()

Comment: Only filtering I've done before is in a viewmodel for dropdowns so can you provide more details as to where I would need to do what you replied with and how possibly that would affect/interact with the telerik grid?

Comment: How are you getting your data that you Bind to your Grid? Normally if it is coming from the database if you have a sql query, stored procedure, or if your using a Entity Framework layer whatever place is querying your database for the resultset that will populate the Grid.

Comment: I've resolved it now so unless what I have to do to fix the other problem I'm having affects this then this issue is now resolved.