# How to get a Telerik Grid filtered based on previous page selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid

What I'm trying to do:-

Index page would have a dropdown of say categories, select 1 then submit, redirected to telerik grid page with all records kept from a big table of selected category.

so for example pet store, dropdown for which type of pets the store has then on next page a grid is populated with all pets of that type which the store has available today.

already got the date filter sorted since that's applied to the databind.

database is connection via an edmx, it has 2 table with no relationships but there is say a category/pet table which goes into details for each category/pet and then there is a record table which has a category/pet column of which the 2 tables have that single field incommon.

I have been trying to get this to work by using ViewData which works perfectly fine for the drop down <%: Html.DropDownList("category", (SelectList)ViewData["CategoryList"])%> but fails to populate the grid on the next page.

so something sorta like http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/selectionserverside but if possible with a dropdown and across 2 pages.

Comment: I know it is at least correctly storing and then displaying the right info since I added in a <%= ViewData["Ward"]%> on the grid page and it showed the correct value but think half the reason it doesn't  display anything and the original way I had to do this didn't work is because my project is slightly different and uses different fields but then the fact the only field it can use as reference is a string and not a int causes hiccups.

Comment: still working on it and the other solutions suggested but most require drastic changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs.

*Telerik Grid for ASP.NET MVC is using its built-in Linq-based expression engine to perform the grid operations - paging, sorting and filtering. However in some cases the developer may want to bypass the expression engine and page, sort or filter the grid data by himself. This is called "Custom binding".*

Heres the link:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-data-binding-custom-binding.html

as per the example; if this was your controller that loaded your page:

```
[GridAction]
public ActionResult Index(GridCommand command)
{
    IEnumerable<Order> data = GetData(command);
    var dataContext = new NorthwindDataContext();
    //Required for pager configuration
    ViewData["total"] = dataContext.Orders.Count();

    return View(data);
}
```

Then your post back would be a place you could filter this:

```
[GridAction]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(GridCommand command)
{
    desiredCategory = this.myDropDownList.SelectedCategory.ToString();

    //Change the query here using post back variables
    IEnumerable<Order> data = GetData(command);
    data = from x in data.[entity name]
           where x.category = desiredCategory
           select x;

    var dataContext = new NorthwindDataContext();

    //Required for pager configuration
    ViewData["total"] = dataContext.Orders.Count();

    return View(data);
}
```

Comment: not sure if it's just information overload with that link or the fact I've been trying to resolve this for most of today but with looking at that link it's not rly clicking and that example seems a bit too specific to just totals so any chance you can go into detail as to how I might resolve this plz

Comment: but how would the post back be setup to filter it since you didn't show that and how would you correctly setup the next page to accept what ever it needs to in order to then filter the telerik grid?

Comment: I ended up using a different method but since this looks like it should work unless I'm told otherwise I'll leave this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same thing, so I just use jQuery to get the data for each page  (Replace #category with the ID of your category dropdown):

```
    function onDataBinding(e) {
        showWaitDialog();
        var grid = $('#Grid').data('tGrid');

        var args = 'page=' + e.page + '&category' + $('#category').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Search/AjaxBinding/",
            type: "POST",
            data: args,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                grid.total = data.total;
                grid.dataBind(data.data);
                hideWaitDialog();
            }
        });

    }
```

Add this to your Grid code:

```
.ClientEvents(x => x.OnDataBinding("onDataBinding"))
```

Controller code:

```
    [GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
    public ActionResult AjaxBinding(int page, int category)
    {

        var searchResultsViewModel = //Code to get search results

        return View(new GridModel
                        {
                            Data = searchResultsViewModel.SearchResults,
                            Total = searchResultsViewModel.TotalCount
                        });
    }
```

Pass the category back, and filter the results before putting it into the grid.

Comment: can you go into a bit more detail about how I would pass the category into it and then filter based on that plz

Answer (score 0):

I can give a few directions without any code (my MVC is a bit rusty and I lack time to code samples).

So basically you have one page where the dropdown is and then another page where the grid will be.
What you need is:

- have the first page submit to the grid page (form action pointing to grid page instead of itself)
- on the grid page see if you receive the input value from the dropdown, if so then filter your data based on that value before binding the grid
- emit a hidden field on this page where you store the filter value received from the dropdown so it is not lost when paging the grid
- basically check for either dropdown value or hidden field value in order to filter the grid

HTH